# Adding Google to the Internet Accounts is not working

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google, google-sync

After changing networks where i used a proxy to go online back home I got the message in Chrome that my login details are not up-to-date. I tried to log me in and it works until I close the browser. If I open it again, the same error comes again.

After googling I tried the following; nothing worked for me:

- Make a new profile in Chrome for my Google-Account
- Reinstalling Chrome and set up everything from scratch

After that, I tried to remove my account in the System Settings. I removed the account and deleted all passwords. However, when I try to make a new account, it get stuck after I entered the password and want to accept the preferences (see screeenshot). It is stuck now for nearly an hour. Maybe someone has a solution for me

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it for me. I had to restart my computer. After that it worked without any issue.